# Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets where $\,\left|X\right|=\left|Y\right|,\,$ then $\,\left|P\left(X\right)\right|=\left| P\left(Y\right)\right|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

We are basically being asked to prove that if the cardinality of set $\,X\,$ and set $\,Y\,$ is the same, then how can we prove that the cardinality of their power sets is also the same.

I have considered using the Schroder Bernstein theorem (If $\,A\,$ and $\,B\,$ are sets with $\,\left\lvert A\right\rvert \le \left\lvert B\right\rvert,\,$ and $\,\left\lvert B\right\rvert \le \left\lvert A\right\rvert,\,$ then $\,\left\lvert A\right\rvert = \left\lvert B\right\rvert.\,$ In other words, if there are one-to-one functions $\,f\,$ from $\,\left\lvert A\right\rvert\,$ to $\,\left\lvert B\right\rvert\,$ and $\,g\,$
from $\,\left\lvert B\right\rvert\,$ to $\,\left\lvert A\right\rvert,\,$ then there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\,A\,$ and $\,B$ )
but I am unsure of how to employ it in a formal proof.

Comment: Let $f$ be a one to one onto function from $A$ to $B$. From $f$ you should be able to produce an explicit one to one onto function $F$ from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$. No fancy stuff needed, no Cantor-Bernstein.

Answer (score 3):

We have a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $B$. What function comes to mind from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$?

> Send $S\subseteq A$ to $f(S)$ and prove this correspondence is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 2):

$|A|=|B|$ means that there exists a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$. This bijection induces a function $f:P(A)\rightarrow P(B)$ by setting $f(S)=\{ f(s) : s\in S \}$ for $S\subset A$. It is then a very easy exercise to see that this is a bijection...

Comment: I am not sure how to prove that F: P(A) -> P(B) is a bijection. could you provide me with more information?

Comment: This follows from the bijectivity of f, hence existence of f^-1. You can recover S from f(S) by applying f^-1, which immediately establishes injectivity. For surjectivity you argue similarly to see that f(f^-1(T))=T given any subset T of B.