# If the set A is smaller than the set B, then is the powerset of A smaller than the powerset of B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for a proof that, given two sets $A$ and $B$, the cardinality of $A$ is less than $B$ implies the cardinality of the powerset of $A$ is less than the cardinality of the powerset of $B$.

In short, does $\overline{\overline {A}}<\overline{\overline {B}}\ \ $  imply   $ \ \ \overline{\overline {P(A)}} < \overline{\overline {P(B)}}$?

There seems to exist a clear method of proof for when $A$ and $B$ are finite (nonempty) sets, since there cannot exist a bijection between a finite set and a proper subset of itself, and hence $\overline{\overline {A}}<\overline{\overline {B}}$ implies there exists a bijection between $A$ and a proper subset of $B$, which one could use to construct a bijection between $P(A)$ and a proper subset of $P(B)$ and then apply the fact that there exists no bijection from $P(B)$ to a proper subset of itself.

But what about when $A$ and $B$ are infinite? How would we know that the proper subset of $P(B)$ which is bijective to $P(A)$ is not also bijective to $P(B)$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439021/prove-that-if-x-and-y-are-sets-where-leftx-right-lefty-right-th.

Comment: The question linked in @palmpo's comment is different. It asks about an easy theorem of ZF. The present question asks about something that is not provable, even in ZFC.

Comment: But the link given at the top of the question (to justify closing it as a duplicate) is correct.

Comment: I thought the present question was asking if $\lvert A\rvert<\lvert B\rvert$ implies $\lvert P(A)\rvert<\lvert P(B)\rvert$.

Comment: Oh but I guess to show there cannot be a bijection from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$, suppose there is one, then $\lvert P(A)\rvert=\lvert P(B)\rvert$. And then it looks like the next step is showing a bijection from $A$ to $B$, i.e. $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert B\rvert$, contradicting $\lvert A\rvert<\lvert B\rvert$. The question I linked only shows $\lvert P(A)\rvert\le\lvert P(B)\rvert$.